# Why is Oracle app failing?

Tags: oracle

I have limited Oracle exp. I wrote app for both SQL Server and Oracle, asp.net c#.
SQL Server works fine. Oracle one client is not able to run the app. The log shows that the sp starts and then does not do anything. Then the app aborts.

My question is how do i get to debug what is going on? Is it the stored procedures I should focus on?

The App was tested in our Oracle server and it worked on our test server.

I need guidance as to what the problem is, and/or how to discover what the problem is. Then we can think about solving.
Here is some info from the log:

```
4-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper :  GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.MissedMedications.Views.MedicineTileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.Orders.Views.OrderTileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.Schedules.Views.ScheduleTileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.MissingAllergies.Views.MissingAllergiesTileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.POWarnings.Views.POWarningsTileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.Decline.Views.DeclineTileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.CNA.Views.CNATileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.Improved.Views.ImprovedTileView)
04-27-2012|INFO: AutoGrid : ArrangeChildren. True, 0
04-27-2012|INFO: AutoGrid : Arranging children in 1 column(s) by 2 row(s).
04-27-2012|INFO: AutoGrid : ArrangeChildren. True, 11
04-27-2012|INFO: AutoGrid : Arranging children in 2 column(s) by 6 row(s).
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetInstance(Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager, '')
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetInstance(OPTFDashboard.Common.UserInterface.MainWindow.MainWindowViewModel, '')
04-27-2012|INFO: Database : Query: SELECT MODULE_ID, DESCRIPTION FROM OGEN.DBD_C_MODULES WHERE ACTIVE = 1
04-27-2012|INFO: Database : Query: SELECT CODKEY, DESCR FROM OGEN.PAT_C_STATES WHERE FACILITY_KEY = 'BASE' ORDER BY DESCR
04-27-2012|INFO: Database : Query: SELECT CODKEY, DESCR FROM OGEN.PAT_C_FAC_REGION
04-27-2012|INFO: Database : Query: SELECT CORP_KEY, CORP_NAME FROM OGEN.GEN_M_CORPORATION ORDER BY CORP_NAME
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.UserInterface.MainWindow.MainWindowView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Bootstrapper : GetAllInstances(OPTFDashboard.Common.UserInterface.MainWindow.FacilitySelectionView)
04-27-2012|INFO: Database : Query: SELECT R.*, S.MODULE_ID
                           FROM OGEN.GEN_M_USER_ROLE R
```

The info lists here those don't actually run that is the issue I think.

Comment: so the app works sometimes, but not on this one particular client?

Comment: so far they may be the only oracle client but what baffles me is that it works when i tested in 4 test servers we have

Comment: can you do what the app does using sqlplus with the same credentials as the app uses ? (connect/query/update/insert your tables) Do you check connection status?

Comment: it turns out the code was the fault. I fixed this.  The schedule's tile wasn't trimming the facility key before calculating its length. Inside of the schedules queries we have code like the following:

TO_DATE(SUBSTR(M.MDS_FILE, LENGTH(S.FACILITY_KEY) + 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')

In oracle, the facility_key column is a char(4).  Some facilities have identified less than 4 characters.  This would result is the length of the facility key always being 4.  I modified the s.facility_key to instead be rtrim(s.facility_key).

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. You should post that as an answer and select it. (instead of choosing something that wasn't your solution as the accepted answer; in my opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Oracle service started, is the connection string valid, can you tnsping the oracle server?
Do you have user privileges set?

Comment: I will check that possibility. I think it is connecting bec other tabs in the app work, this app is a dashboard with many tabs.

Comment: Then you will need to provide more info. Can you put breakpoint or set the application to break on all errors and then see where it breaks and what is the error message.